# Передать значение в input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть для примера следующая форма для заявки:

```
 <ul class="border"><h2>ДЕКАБРЬ:</h2> 
    <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Online">
        <b>Занятие 1:</b> 
        <p>▸ 9 декабря — 20 декабря </p>
    </li>
    <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Online">
        <b>Занятие 2:</b> <br>
        <p>▸ 9 декабря — 20 декабря </p>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="border"><h2>❄ЯНВАРЬ:</h2> 
    <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Online">
        <b>Занятие 1:</b> 
        <p>▸ 13 января — 24 января </p>
    </li>
    <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Online">
        <b>Занятие 2:</b> <br>
        <p>▸ 13 января — 24 января </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

При клике на li открывается форма в модальном окне, где заполняются данные  пользователя:

```
<form action="mailer.php" method="post" id="formID" >
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="month" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Ваше имя*" name='name'>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Контактный номер телефона*" name='tel'>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name='mail'>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="Submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Как можно передать в input hidden данные о месяце и типе занятий из блока на котором был клик?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const form = document.getElementById('formID');
const inputType = document.querySelector('input[name="type"]');
const inputMonth = document.querySelector('input[name="month"]');

[...document.querySelectorAll('li')].map(li => {
  li.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const element = e.currentTarget;
    
    const bText = element.querySelector('b').textContent;
    const pText = element.querySelector('p').textContent;

    
    inputType.value = bText;
    inputMonth.value = pText;
  });
});
```

```html
 <ul class="border"><h2>ДЕКАБРЬ:</h2> 
    <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Online">
        <b>Занятие 1:</b> 
        <p>▸ 9 декабря — 20 декабря </p>
    </li>
    <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Online">
        <b>Занятие 2:</b> <br>
        <p>▸ 9 декабря — 20 декабря </p>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="border"><h2>❄ЯНВАРЬ:</h2> 
    <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Online">
        <b>Занятие 1:</b> 
        <p>▸ 13 января — 24 января </p>
    </li>
    <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Online">
        <b>Занятие 2:</b> <br>
        <p>▸ 13 января — 24 января </p>
    </li>
</ul>

<form action="mailer.php" method="post" id="formID" >
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="month" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Ваше имя*" name='name'>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Контактный номер телефона*" name='tel'>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name='mail'>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="Submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, просто Есус <3